# namespace std and LLVM PassManagerInternal.h file

Tags: c++, llvm, c++14, bison, flex-lexer

I'm exploring compiler writing with Flex, Bison and LLVM (latest versions of all) using this example: http://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/ 
Github source is on the last page of that link. I can't get it to compile and any help would be appreciated.

Unfortunately for me, the solution is non-obvious.

Here are the errors:

```
In file included from codegen.cpp:2:
In file included from ./codegen.h:8:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.8.1/include/llvm/IR/PassManager.h:46:
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.8.1/include/llvm/IR/PassManagerInternal.h:298:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'make_unique'
    return make_unique<ResultModelT>(Pass.run(IR, AM));
           ^
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.8.1/include/llvm/IR/PassManagerInternal.h:298:24: error: unexpected type name 'ResultModelT': expected expression
    return make_unique<ResultModelT>(Pass.run(IR, AM));
                       ^
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.8.1/include/llvm/IR/PassManagerInternal.h:336:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'make_unique'
    return make_unique<ResultModelT>(Pass.run(IR));
           ^
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.8.1/include/llvm/IR/PassManagerInternal.h:336:24: error: unexpected type name 'ResultModelT': expected expression
    return make_unique<ResultModelT>(Pass.run(IR));
                       ^
codegen.cpp:36:24: error: no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'unique_ptr<llvm::Module>' to 'llvm::EngineBuilder'
        ExecutionEngine *ee = EngineBuilder( unique_ptr<Module>(module) ).create();
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/anaconda/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/ExecutionEngine.h:493:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion
      from 'unique_ptr<llvm::Module>' to 'llvm::EngineBuilder' for 1st argument
class EngineBuilder {
      ^
/anaconda/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/ExecutionEngine.h:493:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion
      from 'unique_ptr<llvm::Module>' to 'const llvm::EngineBuilder' for 1st argument
/anaconda/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/ExecutionEngine.h:525:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'unique_ptr<llvm::Module>'
      to 'llvm::Module *' for 1st argument
  EngineBuilder(Module *m) : M(m) {
  ^
codegen.cpp:131:49: warning: expression with side effects will be evaluated despite being used as an operand to 'typeid'
      [-Wpotentially-evaluated-expression]
                std::cout << "Generating code for " << typeid(**it).name() << endl;
                                                              ^
In file included from codegen.cpp:2:
In file included from ./codegen.h:8:
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.8.1/include/llvm/IR/PassManager.h:207:22: error: no member named 'getName' in 'llvm::Module'
               << IR.getName() << "\n";
                  ~~ ^
codegen.cpp:30:5: note: in instantiation of member function 'llvm::PassManager<llvm::Module>::run' requested here
        pm.run(*module);
           ^
In file included from codegen.cpp:2:
In file included from ./codegen.h:8:
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.8.1/include/llvm/IR/PassManager.h:517:20: error: no member named 'getName' in 'llvm::Module'
             << IR.getName() << "\n";
                ~~ ^
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.8.1/include/llvm/IR/PassManager.h:372:28: note: in instantiation of member function
      'llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Module>::invalidateImpl' requested here
    return derived_this()->invalidateImpl(IR, std::move(PA));
                           ^
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.8.1/include/llvm/IR/PassManager.h:217:22: note: in instantiation of member function
      'llvm::detail::AnalysisManagerBase<llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Module>, llvm::Module>::invalidate' requested here
        PassPA = AM->invalidate(IR, std::move(PassPA));
                     ^
codegen.cpp:30:5: note: in instantiation of member function 'llvm::PassManager<llvm::Module>::run' requested here
        pm.run(*module);
           ^
```

Comment: I just edited the source header files. However, if anyone knows a less intrusive workaround, i'd love to hear it.

Comment: Can you please report the list of headers you're seeing this issue? They are likely referring to `llvm::make_unique` but don't include the right header themselves. It is not caught in-tree because they're probably used in implementation files that include it.

Comment: @Joky PassManagerInternal.h (in the title). Here's the example I'm working through. It's github link is at the end. http://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is `llvm::make_unique` in `include/llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h`. You have not stated if you are writing your own code based on llvm source or compiling llvm or what but I assume `llvm::make_unique` is there exactly for that reason to fill the missing pieces of C++11.

Moreover, looking at the [tutorials](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl02.html) it seems that `llvm::make_unique` is explicitly used everywhere.

**Update**

So I successfully build the given example against LLVM 3.9.0 from svn. I had to change and fix all the calls to `getGlobalContext()` since that is gone in LLVM 3.9.0, but I did not encounter any `make_unique` related issues. However the example itself is a bit broken. `codegen.h` is missing an include guard, `codegen.cpp` is missing an include to `#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"`, even if it wants to use the old `getGlobalContext()` method. I did this on Windows with MSVC 2015, can you specify your environment and compiler so that I can try the same?

Comment: Please take a look at the link I posted in the above comments. That will give you a crystal clear picture.

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin ok, I have a compiled version of llvm on my laptop at home, I'll take a look if I can compile this example.

Comment: Awesome. I have compiled a couple of other programs from within Xcode, as well as default Mac Terminal - all using Flex, Bison and LLVM, and either C++ or Objective-C. This one particular example is not working for me, though. I also wrote the author and he basically just said to try it with the (older) versions he wrote it in. That's going to be my last option.

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin well, I gave it a quick look, and it must be something wrong with the example - I mean the PassManagerInternal.h is properly including STLExtras.h and all of the references to `make_unique` are from  `llvm` namespace.

Comment: Ya, that was my thinking.

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin to speed things up, maybe you can post the error messages you get when compiling the example in the question? Then we'd see the source locations where the instantiation of `make_unique` actually breaks stuff. Currently we only see the error, not what's causing it.

Comment: Done. Cleaned up the question, as well. I probably should've just started with that... Though, I didn't want to give the impression that I just fired up my command line and dumped all the errors onto Stack.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at the error messages? I still need help on this.

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin, I updated the answer, I was able to build on windows with llvm 3.8.0, so it means something bad is happening with your environment too. So please post the compiler and llvm versions u are using, I'll try to match that.

Comment: llvm 3.8.1, bison 2.3, flex 2.6.1 on 2015 MBP Terminal using OS Yosemite

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin ok, I'll see if I can match that.

Comment: dope. Don't lose any sleep over it, though. Kinda late where I'm at.

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin did you try fixing the things I mentioned in my answer in your copy of the repo? Maybe the include guards or missing includes mess smth up on OS X ?

Comment: It's first on my list for tomorrow. I didn't know which flex and bison versions you were using, as well as it being VS on a PC so I wasn't in a huge rush. I was also corresponding with the author, but ultimately proved unfruitful.

Comment: I followed the instructions on LLVM.org page to build from source and used their provided examples. I think I just built it wrong.